# plugin for computing and inputing relative path

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

I am editing file `a.js` in directory `/b/c/e/f/g`. I am writing ...

```
b = require('../dontRememberPath/b.js')
```

So to remember path of `b.js` in my project I need to:

1. Find `b.js`
2. See its path
3. Compute its relative path to `a.js` in my head.

And these actions are rather often.

**Do anyone know a plugin for `sublime 3` to automate this routine?**

Just imagine:
This plugin should be opened on file `a.js`, there you input `b.js` and plugin finds path of `b.js` and computes its relative path to `a.js` and inserts it in `a.js` near cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created such plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os.path

class RelativeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):

        clipboard = sublime.get_clipboard()
        fileName = self.view.file_name()
        for pos in self.view.sel():
            self.view.insert(edit, pos.begin(), os.path.relpath(clipboard, fileName)[3:])
```

It gets absolute path of file `b.js` from clipboard, gets absolute path of currently opened file - it is path of `a.js`. Then coumputes their relative path and inserts  to cursor of current open file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like [AutoFileName](https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName)?

Comment: Did you try the st3 branch? Well I should say I wasn't sure it was compatible with ST3. I just know it does something similar in ST2. Looks like you solved the issue anyways.